# How to quickly/temporarily display output of a material node?

Tags: rendering, materials, shader-nodes

Does anyone know how to display the output of a single node from the material editor in the viewport?

I've seen a few artists using it in tutorials, but cannot find any link to the shortcut.

Comment: ctrl+shift+click with the node wrangler enabled?

Comment: you are my hero

Comment: Please don't edit the title with the word "SOLVED" if you have an answer. This is not a regular forum, but a question and answer website. If you find a solution, provide it as an answer even if it's to your own question. That is the format of Stack Exchange websites. This way it will be convenient for people looking for the answer to find it in fraction of a second, if they are used to Stack Exchange format.

Comment: im just looking for an answer mate. correct as much spelling and formatting as you like

Comment: It's also for anyone who finds this in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> + click quickly previews clicked node, if you have Node Wrangler add-on enabled in the  preferences(Edit->Preferences), add-ons tab:

[image]